# How to block outgoin domain request

Tags: dns, ping, hosts

I have a server. I want to make possible sending requests to this server from the internet (this works) and simultaneously block requests from the server to domains.

I want to type

```
ping google.com
```

on the server and see **nothing**.

Now I see

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.205.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mil04s24-in-f46.1e100.net (216.58.205.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=36.3 ms
64 bytes from mil04s24-in-f46.1e100.net (216.58.205.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=63.7 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block any tcp / udp outgoing traffic using the iptables firewall rules.

For example, you can block any outgoing TCP traffic from port 5050 with below firewall rule -

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 4050 -j DROP
iptables save
```

Similarly to block ping request, you can block ICMP protocol for any outbound traffic.